# Injecting Translator service to FormType

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to find a the most reusable working option for being able to translate from a FormType.

**My first option** is to declare a service specifically for each FormType this way:

services.yml

```
form.enquiry:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EnquiryType
    arguments: [@translator]
```

EnquiryType.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
class EnquiryType extends AbstractType {

    public $translator;
    public function __construct(Translator $translator=null)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $tr= $this->translator;
    $msg=$tr->trans('default_error');
    $builder->add ...
```

MyController.php

```
 $form = $this->container->get('form.enquiry')->create();
 return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Home:index.html.twig', array(
     'form' => $form->createView()
 ));
```

gives this error

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EnquiryType::create()

I'd like to know how to solve it by changing the code or even better finding a better option that allows me to inject the translator service to any FormType without needing to declare each FormType service individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd like to know how to solve the injecting issue, I finally managed to find a better solution, just simply overriding the form error rendering by Twig including this block on my custom twig theme, including the trans filter.

```
{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {#
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>#}
        {% for error in errors %}
            <div class="field_error">{{ error.message |trans}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `EnqurityType` must return whole form so inside buildForm You should create whole form

```
$builder
->setAction('action')
->setMethod('POST')
->add('field', 'field_type')
```

And in constructor You should type hint for `TranslatorInterface` its called design by contract

Comment: The buildForm() of course has the  $builder->add lines, just omitted on the code as there were not relevant for this issue. So how the services.yml and the use &_construct from the enquiryType should be?

Comment: If You have fields defined in `formBuilder` delete `create` and constructor should look like `public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator=null)`

Comment: Done as suggested but then get this error :  Call to undefined method Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EnquiryType::createView() . On the other side I'm getting a null value for $translator , should I change services.yml too?

Comment: O sorry hasnt notice you are missing `tag` in your service definition `tags:
            - { name: form.type }`

Answer (score 1):

To make it work properly with Dependency Injection you need to tag it as a form.type:

```
tags:
    - { name: form.type }
```

also do not get it from container like a usual service, but use controller helper as it was a normal formType:

```
$this->createForm(...)
```

Take a look into: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_dependencies.html